# Cakephp Model constants in controller

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I am working in a **CakePHP** project. I am getting the error: `Class 'Book' not found`, when trying to access a model constant from a controller.

In my model I declared a const named 'TYPE'

```
class Book extends AppModel {
       const TYPE = 0; 
}
```

In the controller I loaded the model using:

```
 public $uses = array('Book');
```

In my index I try to access the constant using:

```
Book::TYPE;
```

In other controllers it's working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `App::uses('ModelName', 'Model');` before you declare your controller class. E.g.

```
App::uses('Book', 'Model');

class BooksController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        var_dump(Book::TYPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine. But In some controller I don't have to explicitly load the model.  public $uses = array('Book'); will do it.

Comment: More details on this solution would be appreciated